# Trying to loop through URL's and download images from these webpages

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a nice URL structure and I want to iterate through the URL's and download all the images from the URL's. I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to get the job done, along with the requests function.

Here is the URL - https://sixmorevodka.com/#&gid=0&pid={i}, and I want 'i' to iterate from say 1 to 100 for this example.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests, contextlib, re, os

@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_images(url:str):
  d = soup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser') 
  yield [[i.find('img')['src'], re.findall('(?<=\.)\w+$', i.find('img')['alt'])[0]] for i in d.find_all('a') if re.findall('/image/\d+', i['href'])]

n = 100 #end value
for i in range(n):
  with get_images(f'https://sixmorevodka.com/#&gid=0&pid={i}') as links:
    print(links)
    for c, [link, ext] in enumerate(links, 1):
       with open(f'ART/image{i}{c}.{ext}', 'wb') as f:
           f.write(requests.get(f'https://sixmorevodka.com{link}').content)
```

I think I either messed something up in the Yield line or in the very last write line. Someone help me out please. I am using Python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

In looking at the structure of that webpage, your `gid` parameter is invalid. To see for yourself, open a new tab and navigate to `https://sixmorevodka.com/#&gid=0&pid=22`.

You'll notice that none of the portfolio images are displayed. `gid` can be a value 1-5, denoting the grid to which an image belongs.

Regardless, your current scraping methodology is inefficient, and puts undue traffic on the website. Instead, you only need to make this request once, and extract the urls actually containing the images using the `ilb portfolio__grid__item` class selector.

Then, you can iterate and download those urls, which are directly the source of the images.